spring cloud function as standalone web
I'm trying to run my spring cloud function locally.
According to this configuration, I should be able to run my functions locally as an standalone web application and invoking them using http requests.
I've add:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

However, I hope my spring boot application keeps listening for incoming requests, but it starts and finishes.
I've also tried to add additionally spring-boot-starter-web.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

But it keeps without listening incoming requests.
My parent is:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

Any ideas?

Try to add the "configuration" tag in your pom.xml:
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>

